# php else block not getting called

Tags: php

I am noob in php and I have spent many hours trying to understand why my else block is not getting called. I have tried number of things but just not sure why it is not getting called. I am sure its something stupid i am doing.

```
     <?php   
 $base_url = 'http://localhost/mine/';
     $per_page = 3;                           //number of results to shown per page 
     $num_links = 8;   
     $cur_page = 1;                          // set default current page to 1

if(isset($_REQUEST['string'])<>'') 
{
      $search_string = " title LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%' OR description LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%'";
      $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE ".$search_string);
      $row = mysql_num_rows($query) or die(mysql_error());

      $row = $row; 

      $cur_page = $_GET['page'];
      $cur_page = ($cur_page < 1)? 1 : $cur_page; 
      $offset = ($cur_page-1)*$per_page;                //setting offset

      $pages = ceil($row/$per_page);              // no of page to be created


      $start = (($cur_page - $num_links) > 0) ? ($cur_page - ($num_links - 1)) : 1;
      $end   = (($cur_page + $num_links) < $pages) ? ($cur_page + $num_links) : $pages;

      $res  =   mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE ".$search_string." ORDER BY title LIMIT ".$per_page." OFFSET ".$offset);  

      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
         {
         include ('form.php');
         }
    }
      else
     include ('alert.php');

    ?>
```

i forgot to add that i am using the get method for the url's . So i think it might be possible that even when there is no search term it is still showing index.php?string=
which would mean that it is still taking the if statement as true and not going to the else statement. Please correct me if i am wrong.

here is a snippet from my pagination.php

```
if (strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "?string="))
        {
            echo '<span id="prev"> <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?string=' . $_GET['string'] . '&page=' . (1) . '">' . $dir . '</a> </span>';
        }
        else
            echo '<span id="prev"> <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?page=' . (1) . '">' . $dir . '</a> </span>';
```

Comment: Try to add curly braces and if it doesn't works well add `echo` for debugging step by step.

Comment: `<>` is SQL syntax. The PHP equivalent would be `!=` therefore your `if(isset($_REQUEST['string'])<>'')` should be `if(isset($_REQUEST['string'])!='')`

Comment: curly braces is not necessary when is just one statement after the if/else @user602525, ChoiZ

Comment: <> works perfectly fine in PHP. <> and != are actually 100% interchangeable. That comment is invalid.

Comment: I agree @skrilled my bad.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? I am unable to reproduce your error with PHP 5.5.3.

Comment: The problem is that "isset(xyz) <> ''" is *ALWAYS TRUE*.  POSSIBLE SOLUTION: `if (!isset(xyz) && xyz <> '')`.  BETTER SOLUTION: `if (!empty(xyz))`.

Comment: @paulsm4 that's not true. Check my answer.

Comment: @user3077454 - my comment is correct.  The problem is your "if()".  The best solution - which I noticed Chosen Wann posted 1/2 hour ago - is to substitute "!empty()".  Please upvote and select Chosen Wann's response.

Answer (score 2):

Your IF-condition is wrong

`isset` returns true or false it does not return a value that could be compare to empty or what is between your quotes

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['string']))
```

The above if statement should be enough to check if the value is set and if it's not empty\

Some things you should read

[isset() vs empty() vs is_null()](http://techtalk.virendrachandak.com/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/#axzz2nfqzXvo0)

[empty()'s documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 2):

OP's condition could also be written as `if(!isset($_REQUEST['string']))`

---

**EDIT :**
 I was wrong earlier about:

`<>` is [**SQL syntax**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal)

The PHP equivalent would be `!=` therefore your `if(isset($_REQUEST['string'])<>'')` should be `if(isset($_REQUEST['string'])!='')`

Comment: $a <> $b Not equal TRUE if $a is not equal to $b after type juggling. is valid http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php for more info

Comment: `<>` you can perfectly use that operator, it's not only SQL Syntax. PHP uses it too.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that now. @ChosenWann

Comment: Which could also be written as `if(!isset($_REQUEST['string']))`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Exactly, but I think the OP also wanted to check whether it was empty or not, so using `empty` only is sufficient for what the user needs.

Comment: It's hard to actually pinpoint what the OP is looking to get out of `string`, since we don't see the form or where `string` is being called from. @ChosenWann

Comment: Just saw it now. The OP added extra code to the question. @ChosenWann

Comment: After seeing OP's added code, the `!empty` on your part makes more sense. @ChosenWann

Answer (score 0):

Use

`if(isset($_REQUEST['string'])) { /*...*/ } else { /*...*/ }`

or

`if($_REQUEST['string'] != '') { /*...*/ } else { /*....*/ }`
(while the latter probably throwing a warning in case of the parameter `string` was not passed at all)

Not both at the same time like you did.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this as the condition for the IF:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['string']) && trim($_REQUEST['string'])!=''){ ...
```

First it will check if the variable exists, and if it does, it will check if it has some text in it - just in case

Answer (score 0):

To understand why it's not working, we need to break it apart into parts.

First, you are comparing the value of `isset($_REQUEST['string'])` (which will always return a boolean) to an empty string.

If you do

```
var_dump(isset($_REQUEST['string']));
```

You should see either `bool(true)` or `bool(false)` as the output depending on if it's set.

However when you compare a boolean to a string, it will be type cast the boolean into a string so that both types are the same.

```
var_dump( (string) false ); // Outputs string(0) ""
var_dump( (string) true ); // Outputs string(1) "1"
```

So you are essentially doing the following:

```
// When $_REQUEST['string'] is unset
if ("" <> "") { ... } // Will always be false because "" === ""

// When $_REQUEST['string'] is set
if ("1" <> "") { ... } // Will always be *true* because "1" != ""
```

So therefore, **the reason must be that `$_REQUEST['string']` is, in fact, unset**. I have [tested this myself](http://codepad.org/YRWzWv8u) in PHP 5.5.3:

```
$set_var = 'i_am_set';
var_dump( isset($set_var) <> '' ); // Outputs bool(true)
var_dump(  isset($unset_var) <> '' ); // Outputs bool(false)
```

However, I think that what you're looking for is [empty()](http://php.net/empty) which will return false if the variable is either unset or empty.

Answer (score 0):

Could be in this way, your say you'w using `GET` method

```
$string = isset($_GET['string']) ? $_GET['string'] : NULL;

if(!empty($string ){
   //your stuff
}
```

**Side Note**: read this link [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: You're mixing up `[]`s and `()`s and also didn't put a `$` in front of `string`.

Answer (score -2):

isset() has a boolean return value.

See http://www.php.net/isset.

You should just be able to use it in the if clause.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['string'])) 
{

}
else
{

}
```

You can also use array_key_exists(). See http://www.php.net/function.array-key-exists. This doesn't actually check to make sure that the request parameter has a useful value.

```
if(array_key_exists('string', $_REQUEST)) 
{

}
else
{

}
```

empty() will check for an array key, null, and no value. That's what I'd use.

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['string'])) 
{

}
else
{

}
```

Comment: This only fulfills the user's first condition which is checking if `$_REQUEST['string']` is set or not, it does not fulfill his second condition.

Comment: I assume you mean, if the request parameter has any value. You're probably right empty() is what's called for here.